# How can we keep Ubuntu bluetooth connection "ON" all the time when paired with a Phone?

Tags: bluetooth, connection

I paired Phone and VirtualBox(OS Ubuntu14.4) via Bluetooth successfully, but the Bluetooth connection is "OFF" all the time. How to change it to "ON"? Who have any idea on it? Thanks a lot~